# When I open a list view (Office 365). IE browser crashes and closes

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

When I open a list view (Office 365). IE browser crashes and closes.

Only I have some fields in the view and limit the number of items to display.

Thanks.

Comment: Try asking at sharepoint.stackexchange.com, there you'll find more help about this issue.

Comment: @ArthurCastro Thanks.

Comment: http://itgroove.net/mmman/2016/05/19/trouble-loading-sharepoint-sites-in-ie11-after-upgrading-to-office-2016/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/29347c74-1cb5-4da4-a440-74ea91838252/sharepoint-2013-internet-explorer-crash-ucrtbasedll-office-2016?forum=sharepointgeneral

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173363/sharepoint-2013-ie-11-breaks-when-accessing-sharepoint-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running Internet Explorer in No-Addons Mode (`iexplore -extoff`). Usually an addon would cause the browser to crash and disabling/repairing the addon will fix the issue.